# Rewriting old array to new in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got a query in my model

```
public function get_array()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }  
    }
```

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    if ( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        redirect('login');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array();

        $data['title'] = 'Text_about';

        $data['new_messages_number'] = count($this->about_text_model->new_messages());

        $data['new_messages'] = $this->about_text_model->new_messages();

        $data['about_text_list'] = $this->about_text_model->get_array();

        $ret = array();

        foreach ($data['about_text_list'] as $items)
        {
            $items['about_text_list']['text'] = word_limiter(strip_tags($items['text']), 100);
            $ret[] = $items;
        }

        $data['new_data'] = $ret;

        $name = 'about_text_show';

        $this->display_lib->admin_page($name, $data);               
    }              
}
```

view :

```
<? foreach ($new_data as $line) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="center"><?=$line['language']?></td>
                            <td><?=$line['header']?></td>
                            <td><?=$line['text'];?></td>

                            <td class="center"><?=$line['num']?></td>
                            <td class="center">
                                <a href="<?=base_url().$this->lang->lang();?>/about_text_edit/<?=$line['id']?>"><img src="<?=base_url();?>images/icons/icon_edit.png" alt="" title=""/></a>
                                <a href="?show=about_text&action=delete&id=<?=$line['id']?>"><img src="<?=base_url();?>images/icons/icon_missing.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <? endforeach; ?>
```

Problem is that I get data from SQL and write it to array with all html tags. I need clear text from html and make it shorter. Making array I do it with foreach and rewrite every field to new array (one field "text" I do strip_tags) after I display new array in my view.

I am surprised that my new making array display data without any error and no changes ! 
so where is thise line :

```
$items['about_text_list']['text'] = word_limiter(strip_tags($items['text']), 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code it should be

```
$line['about_text_list']['text']
```

not just

```
<td><?=$line['text'];?></td>
```